# Apache2 .htaccess rewrite rule to Lighttpd

Tags: .htaccess, lighttpd

could you help me to convert this rewrite rule from apache2 to lighttpd

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://my-site\.net/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.my-site\.net/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://player\.my-site\.net/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://stream\.my-site\.net/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Thank you

Comment: @j0k: i have tryed to forbid access to my files from foreign domains.

Comment: I mean, did you try something before coming here and ask for help, which is not really help but more a *could you do that for me because I'm too lazy to search on Google* ...

Comment: yes of course, tryed add it by my self and google. nixcraft has a good article to lighttpd and hotlinking prevention, also here are some good posts. But everything i'm trying, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This will send a 403 instead of 404. But I don't know how to send a different http status code than 403.

```
$HTTP["referer"] =~ "(my\-site\.net)|(www\.my\-site\.net)|(player\.my\-site\.net)|(stream\.my\-site\.net)" {
  url.access-deny = ("")
}
```

You can find other stuffs:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/lighttpd-stop-bandwidth-thief-image-hotlinking.html
- https://admin-serv.net/blog/392/bloquer-les-vilains-referer-sous-lighttpd/ (in french)
- http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/HowToFightDeepLinking