# Lighttpd: How to migrate a rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, lighttpd

i'm using this htaccess rule on a apache:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

.. and i would convert it to an lighttpd rewrite rule. How can i do this? I tried it but it does not work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be answered here:
[Apache2 .htaccess rewrite rule to Lighttpd](https://serverfault.com/questions/447989/apache2-htaccess-rewrite-rule-to-lighttpd)

So something like:

```
$HTTP["referer"] == "example.com" {
    url.access-deny = ("")
}
```

If you need to match the sub-domains too:

```
$HTTP["referer"] =~ "^(.+\.|)example\.com$" {
    url.access-deny = ("")
}
```